# Grails 2.4.2 URL mapping calling the wrong action in controller

Tags: grails, url-mapping, urlmappings.groovy

I'm using Grails 2.4.2 with the RestfulController and this particular controller uses PagingRestfulController.

I'm trying to run the action searchProducts in the Product Controller when I do a GET on "/product/search" but instead it's running queryForResource.

Grails created listAllResources and queryForResource with the "/product"(resources:'product') URL mapping. Below is my URL Mapping and the applicable parts of the Product Controller. How can I call the search action?

**URL Mapping**

```
"/product"(resources:'product')
"/product/search"(controller: 'product'){
    action = [GET: 'searchProducts']
}
```

**Product Controller**

```
protected List<Product> searchProducts(Map params) {
    log.debug("searching products...");
}

protected List<Product> listAllResources(Map params) {
    log.debug("listing all resources...");
}

protected List<Product> queryForResource(Serializable id) {
    log.debug("querying for resources...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a public `search` action in your controller, which might look something like this:

```
def search() {
    searchProducts(params)
}
```

The protected `listAllResources` and `queryForResource` methods override helper methods defined in `RestfulController`, but do not themselves serve as exposed controller actions.

Then, use this nested mapping:

```
"/product"(resources:'product') {
    "/search"(controller: 'product', action: 'search', method: 'GET')
}
```

Comment: It's still running queryForResource

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your help, though it's still running queryForResource

Comment: Update: Adding a search view fixed my issue